# wp INNER JOIN not fetching correct data in my wp website

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, inner-join

i created a simple script for my wp website, 
i am trying to fetch the correct data from wp database of 2 table here is code,

when im displaying the result of column "user_ref_id" is repeating many times,
here is code

```
global $wpdb;
 $tableuser=$wpdb->prefix.'user_shah';
 $tablecopn=$wpdb->prefix.'user_coupons_shah';
$results_count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT User_Status, Coupon_Status, User_ref_id FROM $tableuser t1 INNER JOIN $tablecopn t2 ON t1.User_Status=t2.Coupon_Status WHERE t1.User_Status='1'");

$res_countus = count($results_count);

if($res_countus>0)
{

 echo "<p><select name='autoref' id='myAutoref' onchange='myRefauto()'>
 <option>Select Reference</option>";
 foreach($results_count as $results2)
 { echo "<option value='{$results2->User_ref_id}'>{$results2->User_ref_id}</option>";

 }
 echo "</select></p>";
}
```

Comment: `User_ref_id` will repeat if there are morethan one associations of user exists in `$tablecopn` you need to choose which one should be picked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add GROUP BY clause to your mysql query.

```
$results_count = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT User_Status, Coupon_Status,User_ref_id 
FROM $tableuser t1 INNER JOIN $tablecopn t2 
ON t1.User_Status=t2.Coupon_Status 
WHERE t1.User_Status='1' 
GROUP BY User_ref_id ");
```

Comment: This is invalid query , because using a `group by` without an aggregate function and it will fail if `sql_full_groupby` mode is enabled

Comment: It will work without a problem. If the parameter you told is enabled, it is not a problem to add some count() to select section. It will not affect final result

Comment: [Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) *MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default*

Comment: Thanks ElvinHaci, i have used GROUP BY User_ref_id and its working perfectly as i want, thanks alot dear,

Comment: M Khalid, Thanks for your information related this issue,